# C言語コードのどこに問題がありますか

Tags: c

C2100: 間接指定演算子 (*) の使い方が正しくありません。
error C2143: 構文エラー: ';' が '}' の前にありません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ソースコードは、画像でなくテキストを貼り付けて質問してください。 
[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: コンパイラやIDEが何かとか、その版数の情報も追記して、更に`#include`とかも記述して完結したソースコードにしてください。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) VC++2022だと別の警告やエラーが表示されます。

Comment: [リビジョン1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/95380/1)や2にはソースコードが書かれていたのですが質問者さんによって画像に置き換えられてしまいました。戻そうとも思いましたが、現在の質問コードとも少し違うようなので、質問者さんが質問したいコードで更新されることを待ちたいと思います。その際、エラーメッセージがどの行に対して出力されているかも記載してください。

Comment: プログラムのコードは [Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)辺りを参考に。Markdownの「コードブロック」で行うとよいです

Answer (score 1):

# 回答ではないが長文なので回答欄を使います

編集前のコードを最小限の修正をしてコンパイルしたら C2100 にならない、他のエラーが出る気がします・・・

以下の点がわかっていないようで、結果として全面的に誤っています。

- ポインタと配列の違い
- `int` １個へのポインタと `int` 配列へのポインタの違い
- 配列要素のポインタ経由での呼び出し方
- 自動変数の記憶域期間（寿命）

全部書き直す必要がありそうですが、上記全部を解説すると本が１冊書けちゃいます＝stackoverflow 的にはそんな広範囲すぎる質問は取り扱い範囲外。

一応「回答」という形式を保つなら、全部に問題がありますとなるでしょうか。課題を細分化して文書化できれば（オイラを含めて）回答してくれる人はいっぱいいるでしょう。自分が「何がわかっていないか」を整理してこの質問を編集するなり、この質問はクローズして別途質問を起こすことをお勧めします。

Comment: ごコメントありがとうございました。夜、774RRさんの通り直します。

Answer (score 0):

#### ポインターについて(の回答)

配列をセットする関数と, その内容を表示する関数を用意するなら
(通常は) 関数の戻り値として 配列そのものではなくポインターを返します (無駄なコピーを行わない)

(質問はそのつもりのコードかも知れないけれど)

一次元配列であれば, 比較的容易で
以下のポインターは `int`項目をポイントします
(要素数 3 は, ポインターの宣言には含まれないことに注意)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static int *
init(void)
{
    static int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
    return arr; // 配列の先頭のアドレス
}

static void
output(const int *p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d, ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
    const int *p = init();
    output(p, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

##### 間違ったポインター指定

以下のコードでは `[3][4]` で要素数 12個の配列 へのポインター, という意味になる
インデックス `0`でポイントすると(指し示すと), 12 項目の `int`
また, 「次」の位置 (ptr +1) は 48 Bytes先のアドレス
(質問のコードでは 400 項目の `int` となる)

```c
    const int (*ptr)[3][4];
    printf("ptr size\t%zu \n", sizeof ptr);
    printf("[0] size\t%zu \n", sizeof ptr[0]);
    printf("elem count\t%zu \n", sizeof ptr[0] / sizeof (int));
// ptr size        8
// [0] size        48
// elem count      12

    ptr = (int (*)[3][4])0xdeadbeef0000;
    printf("ptr +0\t%p \n", (const void *)ptr);
    printf("ptr +1\t%p \n", (const void *)(ptr +1));
// ptr +0  0xdeadbeef0000
// ptr +1  0xdeadbeef0030
```

---

二次元配列でアクセスするなら, 実際には 以下のように記述できます
(型宣言は上記同様な感じで)

```c
    const int (*p)[YOKO_MAX] = fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

2次元配列（以下，配列）の初期化のために「配列を初期化し，そのポインタを返す関数」を用いようとしているコードと推察されます。
それを前提とすると，記述上の主な問題点としては以下の3点が考えられます。

- 配列のポインタの記述には括弧が必要（括弧がないと配列の要素がポインタの意味になる），（次項を前提に）関数の戻り値の型指定も同様だが更に配列形状の指定も必要
- 関数の戻り値がメイン側の記述（配列のポインタへの代入）と不整合で，戻り値は配列のアドレスにすべき
- 配列の記憶域は関数側で確保（`a`）しているが，処理がメイン側に戻った後も確保を続ける（静的に確保する）には `static` が必要

オリジナルを基に上記の問題点（とその他）を改善した記述例を下記に示します。なお，出力形式を一部変更しています。

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TATE_MAX 20
#define YOKO_MAX 20

int (*createMap(void))[TATE_MAX][YOKO_MAX];

int main(void)
{
     int (*field)[TATE_MAX][YOKO_MAX] = createMap();
     int i, j;

     for (i = 0; i < TATE_MAX; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < YOKO_MAX; j++)
               printf(" %2d", (*field)[i][j]);
          printf("\n");
     }
}

int (*createMap(void))[TATE_MAX][YOKO_MAX]
{
     static int a[TATE_MAX][YOKO_MAX];
     int i, j;

     for (i = 0; i < TATE_MAX; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < YOKO_MAX; j++)
               if (i == 0 || i == TATE_MAX - 1
                   || j == 0 || j == YOKO_MAX - 1)
                    a[i][j] = 1;
               else
                    a[i][j] = 0;

     return &a;
}
```

```
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```